# SQL combine columns strings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have an sql table that looks like the following

```
p1   c1   c2    c3     c4    c5    c6    c7
A    B    C      D     E     F     NULL  NULL
A    B    C      NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  
A    B    NULL   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL    
A    NULL NULL   NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL  NULL
```

i need a select sql query with 1 column and the output to look like

```
Result
A > B > C > D > E > F 
A > B > C
A
```

i tried nested select case however i am getting only nulls

```
select 
   case when x.p1 IS not NULL then(
 x.p1 + case when x.c1 IS not NULL then(
  ' > '+ x.c1  + case when x.c2 IS not NULL then(
  ' > '+ x.c2  + case when x.c3 IS not NULL then(
  ' > '+ x.c3  + case when x.c4 IS not NULL then(
  ' > '+ x.c4  + case when x.c5 IS not NULL then(
  ' > '+ x.c5  + case when x.c6 IS not NULL then(
  ' > '+ x.c6  + case when x.c7 IS not NULL then(
  ' > '+ x.c7 )end )end )end )end )end  )end )end) end as tree 
from mytable
```

1. is there a better way to get the result i want?
2. what is wrong with my select case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the fact that in TSQL `'a string' + null` equals `null`, you can simplify the query to this:

```
select 
  p1
  + isnull(('>' + c1), '')
  + isnull(('>' + c2), '')
  + isnull(('>' + c3), '')
  + isnull(('>' + c4), '')
  + isnull(('>' + c5), '')
  + isnull(('>' + c6), '')
  + isnull(('>' + c7), '')
from mytable
```

SQLFiddle link: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02b05/8

---

> what is wrong with my select case?

You are using the table alias `x` which appears to not be defined anywhere.

I made your query work in two steps:

- define the `x` table alias. For that, simply write `mytable x` at the end instead of just `mytable`
- after the above fix, it'll still return null, because the `case` statements only have one branch and when the condition is not met they still return `null`. To fix that, replace every `end` with `else '' end` (to return an empty string rather than a `null`)

Here's your version working: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02b05/11

Comment: And for 2012 this can be shortened to `SELECT p1 + CONCAT('>' + c1,'>' + c2,'>' + c3,'>' + c4,'>' + c5, '>' + c6,'>' + c7) from mytable` [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02b05/1)

Comment: @MartinSmith I think that's so great that it deserves an answer of its own.

Comment: It's only an incremental change to your answer and I guess the OP wants something that will work in both 2008 and 2012 anyway.